# rspec - always responding with status 200 in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a user controller that when a PATCH request is sent to, it will try to authenticate the user and update the user's password. Everything works in the browser (I get 200 when the "current_password" is correct, and 401 when it's incorrect).

But when I try to run the specs, `expect(response.status).to eq(401)` is always failing because I always get 200 as the response, can anyone explain what's going on here?

users_controller.rb:

```
def update

if params[:user].has_key?("current_password") && !(@user.authenticate(params[:user][:current_password]))
  render_response(:not_authorized, { description_detailed: "Unable to authenticate current password" })
else
  @user.update_attributes!(accessible_params)
  render_response(:ok, { data: UserSerializer.new(@user, root: false)})
end
end
```

users_controller_spec.rb:

```
context "when current password field is passed in" do
      let(:name) { Faker::HarryPotter.character.split(' ') }
      let!(:custom_user) do
        create(:user,
          first_name: name[0],
          last_name: name[0],
          email: "test@reset.com",
          password: "correct123"
        )
      end
      context "when current password is correct" do
        before :example do
          patch :update, params: { id: custom_user.id, user: user_params }
        end
        let(:user_params) do
          { current_password: "correct123", password: "newpassword123" }
        end
        it "updates user's password with new password" do
          expect(custom_user.authenticate('correct123')).to eq(custom_user)
          expect(response.status).to eq(200)
        end
      end
      context "when current password is incorrect" do
        let(:user_params) do
          { user: {
            current_password: "incorrect1235",
            password: "newpassword123"
          }}
        end
        before :example do
          patch :update, params: { id: custom_user.id, user: user_params }
        end
        it "does not update user's password" do

          expect(custom_user.authenticate('incorrect1234')).not_to eq(custom_user)
          expect(response.status).to eq(401)
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are testing for the hash keys in string form in the controller...

```
if params[:user].has_key?("current_password")
```

but passing them in symbol form in the test...

```
user: {
            current_password: "incorrect1235",
```

If you look at the parameters in controller in this case, you will find the key is:

```
:current_password
```

This also points out a dangerous flaw in your code -- a user's password can be updated if "current_password" is not supplied in the update parameters. In this instance the else block is always called and the user is never authenticated.

Suggest testing for the presence the current_password and returning an error if it is not supplied.